# Add a class name to element immediately this element is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, jquery-events

I have an element which has to be hidden when JavaScript is enabled. The current code seems like this:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="js-hidden"></div>
    ...
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#js-hidden').hide();
        })
    </script>
```

There is the problem, the **js-hidden** div is visible since the rest of page (and JavaScripts) are loaded.

Can I hide that earlier? This solution is so bad for me, JS user can´t see this element.

PS: I've written the example with using jQuery, it can be in plain JS too, of course :-)

Comment: why don't just hide display using css

Comment: u need to add a class while load is that wat u need..working version http://jsbin.com/izAgUbI/1/edit

Comment: use style="display:none" for the div

Comment: are you looking for [<noscript/>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(document).ready makes it happen after **full page** loaded you can use

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="js-hidden"></div>
    ...
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <div id="js-hidden"></div>
    <script>

            $('#js-hidden').hide();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest thing:

```
<style>
.js-hidden {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<noscript>
<style>
.js-hidden {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use onload event on div I guess the best solution is put your js right after that div...